# Where can I get physical CDs of Ubuntu if I live in a place with limited internet connectivity?

Tags: cd, locoteams

I am based in Durban, South Africa and would like to get a copy of the operating system but do not have an internet connection. Can someone nearby help me make a CD copy?

Comment: I hope you find someone nearby, but what I do not understand is that if you don't have a network connection, then how are you posting here??

Comment: @pawan He says 'limited internet connectivity'. So the OP probably has a slow ISP provider like dial-up or access to internet is limited to when the OP can get to the library or whatever.

Answer (score 9):

Why don't you try and get in contact with the South Africa LoCo team

http://ubuntu-za.org/

or subscribe to their mailing list

https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-za

They have a couple of release parties set up, I'd expect you could get a CD there

http://ubuntu-za.org/news/2012/04/19/precise-pangolin-release-parties

You can look up information for getting CDs from nearby enthusiast by contacting your closes Ubuntu local team:

- http://loco.ubuntu.com/
- http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=183
- http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/locallanguage
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IRC/ChannelList