# Can I get new CD or DVD of ubuntu? Also softwares?

Tags: server, software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get an Ubuntu Installation CD or DVD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79715/where-can-i-get-an-ubuntu-installation-cd-or-dvd)
>   [Where can I get physical CDs of Ubuntu if I live in a place with limited internet connectivity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126388/where-can-i-get-physical-cds-of-ubuntu-if-i-live-in-a-place-with-limited-interne)

From where,Can I get new CD or DVD of ubuntu? Also softwares and drivers?

Comment: @fossfreedom  I've done a major edit to http://askubuntu.com/questions/79715/where-can-i-get-an-ubuntu-installation-cd -- it looks like a merge would be good.